# Can these two sentences coexist in the same contexts?

Tags: writing

[image]

[image]

Can sentence “the white semicircle became black” and “the white semicircle disappeared” coexist in the same contexts? Or are they two different interpretations?

I’m preparing for some exam.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about "subjective" logic and perception, not the use of language as such

Comment: True, but this is like preparing for university maths test by doing a very odd piece of arithmetic.  This isn't helping you prepare the skills you need for TOEIC.   If you want to practice photo description try  https://unsplash.com/s/photos/people-at-work (not associated)  Those are much closer to the kind of thing you need to describe

Comment: @James K Can I ask picture-description questions in the uncertain future if I really really really don’t know?

Comment: You are always welcome to ask questions that are based on real problems that you have.

Comment: This is not an English language problem, the same question could be asked about any language; Italian, Hindi, Lao, Russian... This is a question about **interpretation** and like Kate Bunting said, remove the white semicircle (disappeared), you're left with a black semicircle. Who says the white section changed colour? I see a black circle.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean the shape above became the shape below.

Yes, you could say the white semicircle became black or disappeared.

It depends on what the circles are supposed to mean. The context matters to the semiotics of the situation.

Essentially, a certain sign was replaced with a different sign. How we describe this would depend on the function and purpose of these signs, and so is strongly context dependent.

Comment: Luke edited the post. I thought it was “and.”

Comment: "or" works well for me.  Good edit.

Comment: Then, “the white semicircle became black and dissapeared” is wrong.

Comment: Not wrong.  But its all impossible to say. Really "There was one symbol, and then there was a different one"  Without knowing the context you can't say how one symbol changed to the other.  This is particularly the case because these are abstract symbols.

Comment: If I make it concrete, it may be “chameleons became green on the green grass and disappeared.”

Comment: That's fine.  But of course that's not the same as circles.

Comment: Kate said If the white semicircle disappeared, you would be left with just the black one, not with a black circle. Is it true?

Comment: There is no special treatment in Enlglish.  Apply the rules for your language. Is  the first shape a "Black circle with a white semicircle on top, the white one has a slightly smaller radius" or is it "A black semicircle next to a white semicircle outlined in black"  This is **nothing** to do with English grammar or idiom.  There is **nothing** to learn about English here!

Comment: If my native language is English and I’m 8 and monolingual, are you gonna believe it?

Comment: No, because few native eight-year-olds use words like "monolingual"!